# C++: Accessing a data member of an instance of class A (holding a list of class B objects) from a B object

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Value
{
    public:
        void set(const int intValue){ intValue_ = intValue; }
        int read() const { return intValue_; }
        void replaceIfInMap(){
            std::map<int,int>::iterator it;
            it = valuesToReplace_->find(intValue_);
            if(it != valuesToReplace_->end()){
                intValue_ = it->second;
            }
        }
        Value(std::map<int,int>* valuesToReplace) : valuesToReplace_(valuesToReplace){}
    private:
        std::map<int,int>* valuesToReplace_;
        int intValue_;
};

class Holder    {  
    public:
        void doStuffWithValues(){
            Value a(&valuesToReplace_), b(&valuesToReplace_), c(&valuesToReplace_);
            a.set(1); b.set(2); c.set(3);
            valuesToReplace[2]=5;
            a.replaceIfInMap(); b.replaceIfInMap(); c.replaceIfInMap();
            std::cout << "a: "  << a.read()
                      << " b: " << b.read() 
                      << " c: " << c.read() << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        std::map<int,int> valuesToReplace_;
};

int main()
{
    Holder holder;
    holder.doStuffWithValues();
}
```

How could I get access to the `valuesToReplace_` member in a more convenient (and preferably more elegant) way? I have considered storing the map as a public static member of the class `Value`, but that would deny the possibility of having multiple instances of the `Holder` class, as each Holder instance requires a set of `Value` instances with different replacement settings.

A global map would be an even uglier "solution"...

Calling `Value::read()` from `Holder` and doing the map interaction there is not an option as this code is only a simplification and in the real code the equivalent of each instance of `Value` can store pointers to other instances of the same class rendering the aforementioned method overly complex and bulky.

Why does the above code even work? `Holder::valuesToReplace_` is private! Is this just normal C++ behaviour (as you cannot get that pointer without access to the private members of the class anyway)?

Comment: Is this helper class really necessary? Looks like all you're doing could be summarized as: `int replace_maybe(int n) { auto it = m.find(n); return it != m.end() ? it->second : n; }`

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the above code even work? Holder::valuesToReplace_ is
>   private!

It is private, so Holder::doStuffWithValues can access it because it is a member function, nothing wrong there.

```
Value a(&valuesToReplace_), b(&valuesToReplace_), c(&valuesToReplace_);
            a.set(1); b.set(2); c.set(3);
```

Here, all your Value objects have valuesToReplace_ pointing to the same map is that what you want? It seems strange, I would either have a static map (which would make a copy on assignment) or a smart pointer to prevent unexpected deletion (but allow NULL values).

> How could I get access to the valuesToReplace_ member in a more
>   convenient (and preferably more elegant) way?

You could keep it private and have public member functions which return begin/end const_iterators for the map, or setIntForInt/getIntForInt accessor methods which are not dependent on internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing a reference to the `valuesToReplace` map to your `replaceIfInMap` method?

```
class Value
{
    public:
        void set(const int intValue){ intValue_ = intValue; }
        int read() const { return intValue_; }

        void replaceIfInMap(std::map<int,int> const& valuesToReplace_){
            std::map<int,int>::const_iterator it;
            it = valuesToReplace_->find(intValue_);
            if(it != valuesToReplace_->end()){
                intValue_ = it->second;
            }
        }

        Value() {}
    private:
        int intValue_;
};

class Holder    {  
    public:
        void doStuffWithValues(){
            Value a, b, c;
            a.set(1); b.set(2); c.set(3);
            valuesToReplace_[2]=5;
            a.replaceIfInMap(valuesToReplace_);
            b.replaceIfInMap(valuesToReplace_);
            c.replaceIfInMap(valuesToReplace_);
            std::cout << "a: "  << a.read()
                      << " b: " << b.read() 
                      << " c: " << c.read() << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        std::map<int,int> valuesToReplace_;
};
```